# Python - create loop to filter and save in separate df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, filter

Hi Pythoners and Pythonistas,

I have a working code that applies three filters over a dataframe. The code is applied on 194 instances which increases the total running time over a bearable level - so now I need to cut it down.

My code:

1_all = df.loc[(df['Country'] == '1') & (df['Unit'] == "Result") & (df['Structure'] == "Total")]

2_all = df.loc[(df['Country'] == '2') & (df['Unit'] == "Result") & (df['Structure'] == "Total")]

3_all = df.loc[(df['Country'] == '3') & (df['Unit'] == "Result") & (df['Structure'] == "Total")]

4_all = df.loc[(df['Country'] == '4') & (df['Unit'] == "Result") & (df['Structure'] == "Total")]

Is it possible to transform this code into a loop-function and will this reduce the overall running time?

Thank you guys in advance - stackoverflow saved me more than once.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single groupby object and loop over it.

Filter only once on Unit/Structure:

```
dfs = {name: g for name,g in 
       (df.loc[(df['Unit'] == "Result") & (df['Structure'] == "Total")]
          .groupby('Country'))
      }
```

Then you can access the values for 1 using

```
dfs['1'] # assuming '1' is a string
```

Comment: Thank's a lot - exactly what I needed! You really saved my day!